# How to completely remove and re-install python (without yum)?

Tags: python, centos5, package-management, reinstall

I have a corrupted / missing installation of Python on a CentOS 5 server, and yum won't help me reinstall because python is a dependency. When I try installing `python-2.4.3-44.el5.x86_64` from the rpm, it informs me that python-libs is required.

But when I try to install python-libs:

> `[root@myserver]# rpm -ivh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/x86_64/CentOS/python-libs-2.4.3-44.el5.x86_64.rpm`
>
> ```
> error: Failed dependencies:
>         python(abi) = 2.4 is needed by python-libs-2.4.3-44.el5.x86_64
> ```

At this point, I would like to purge any remnants of the old installation from my system, and do a completely clean installation. However, I'm unclear on how to completely remove python, and I haven't been able to find a `pythonabi` or `python-abi` package that matches up with version `2.4.3-44.el5.`

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably what I'd do is first find all the easily identifiable python packages:

```
 rpm -qa | grep python
```

Then erase them using

```
 rpm --erase pkg1 ... pkgn
```

If there are dependencies flagged, then if you can include these in the packages to be deleted.

You CAN override the dependency checks by including the

```
 --nodeps
```

flag after the --erase flag on the rpm command line.  Not always recommended of course but sometimes necessary.

Then with all the packages downloaded from what ever source you have you then do:

```
 rpm --install pkg1 ... pkgn
```

Again, if possible satisfy all the dependencies.  But you can override this behavior using the:

```
 --nodeps --force
```

flags after the --install flag.  Again, not always recommended but sometimes necessary.

Comment: How do I get the dependency `python(abi) = 2.4`? I haven't found this package.

Comment: Its probably not a package but as one of the parts of another package.

Comment: `$ rpm -q --whatprovides 'python(abi)'`
`python-2.4.3-27.el5`